# AWK join next 2 rows from csv

Tags: awk

I'm using the following command to join the next row but would like to join the next 2 rows

```
awk -v OFS=', ' 'NR==1{first=$0} NR>1{print prev, $0} {prev=$0} END{print prev, first}' test.csv
```

test.csv

```
rabbit
cat
dog
turtle
sheep
cow
```

Result:

```
rabbit, cat
cat, dog
dog, turtle
turtle, sheep
sheep, cow
cow, rabbit
```

Desired result:

```
rabbit, cat, dog
cat, dog, turtle
dog, turtle, sheep
turtle, sheep, cow
sheep, cow, rabbit
cow, rabbit, cat
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the complete file into memory and then manipulate the columns:

```
$ awk -v OFS="," -v n=3 '{a[NR-1]=$0}END{for(i=0;i<NR;++i) for(j=0;j<n;++j) printf "%s%s",a[(i+j)%NR], (j==n-1?ORS:OFS)}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written in GNU `awk`. Written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS=', ' '
{
  for(i=1;i<=(NF-1);i++){
     printf("%s %s %s %s\n",$i,OFS $(i+1),OFS $(i+2),i==(NF-1)?$1:"")
  }
}
END{
  print $NF,$1,$2
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS=', ' '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=(NF-1);i++){                    ##Running for loop from 1to till 2nd last element of line.
     printf("%s %s %s %s\n",$i,OFS $(i+1),OFS $(i+2),i==(NF-1)?$1:"")    ##Printing current field, OFS next field and next to next field and checking condition if i==NF-1 then print 1st field else print nothing.
  }
}
END{                                         ##Starting END block for this code from here.
  print $NF,$1,$2                            ##Printing last field then 1st and 2nd field here.
}
' Input_file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```